# How do I make it so some Javascript will only run if someone clicks on a link or element?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I am asking this question because from a tutorial I made a rock, paper, scissors game and want it to only run if someone clicks on something to run it. Not where it automatically runs. Please let me know. :)
If you want the coding to the game here it is

```
<script>
confirm("Open up your browsers console to see who wins")
    var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
computerChoice = "rock";
 } else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
computerChoice = "scissors";
 } console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);
 var compare = function (choice1, choice2) 
 {
  if (choice1 === choice2) {
    return "The result is a tie!";
  }
  else if (choice1 ==="rock") { // 1st Choice

    if(choice2 === "scissors") {
        return "rock wins";
    }
    else {
        return "paper wins";
    }
   }
   else if (choice1 === "paper") { // 2nd Choice

    if (choice2 === "rock") {
        return "paper wins";
    }
    else {
        return "scissors wins"   
    }

}
   else if (choice1 === "scissors") { // 3rd Choice

    if (choice2 === "rock") {
        return "rock wins";
    }
     else {
        return "scissors wins";
   }
    }
 };
   compare(userChoice,computerChoice);
    </script>
```

Comment: Possibly worth reading for other ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976883/rock-paper-scissors-in-javascript

Comment: See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html

Answer (score 3):

Most HTML element respond to events. If you want to run a function when you click on a text you can put the text in a `div` element with the `onclick` event that calls your function.

```
<script>
  function func1() {
    alert("First function has been called");
  }
  function func2() {
    alert("Second function");
  }
</script>

This text does nothing
<div onclick="func1()">This does something</div>
This text does nothing
<div onclick="func2()">This does something else</div>
This text does nothing
```

Comment: Suggest to separate JS from HTML. Instead of using `onclick`, try to add event listener to the element.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a button to start the script, you have to do two things:

Enclose the script in a function.  Let's call the function "play".  So you would have

> ```
> <script>
> function play(){
>    ... put the javascript to play the game in here ...
> }
> </script>
> ```

Make a button in the HTML like this:

> `<button onclick='play();'>Play</button>`

This is actually a bad example, although it will work.  Modern thinking on how to write computer programs for the web suggests splitting the javascript and HTML into their own files, setting an `id` instead of `onclick` in the HTML of clickable components like buttons, and setting the `onclick` handler in the javascript file by looking up that `id`.  But, maybe that is too much to learn starting out.  You should learn this eventually though...

Answer (score 0):

Codeacademy? Awesome site for learning. Also, it's really easy to make a blackjack game out of that setup once you're done with that section of the tutorial. So I would save that code