# Why don’t I get any result from this rock-paper-scissors game?

Tags: javascript

Tried to build a simple game (scissors, stone, paper) in JS but don’t really know what I’m doing wrong here. After I do an input in the `prompt` and choose for example `paper` I don’t get any reaction from the code. Can somebody explain it in a very pedagogic way for me? What have I missed?

```
var Number = Math.random()
Number = Number * 10;
Number = Math.round(Number);
var Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 - 0 + 1)) + 0;

console.log (Number);

var userInput = prompt("Choose between scissors, stone or paper. Good luck!").toLocaleLowerCase;

if (Number == 0) {
    Number = "scissors";
} if (Number == 1){
    Number = "stone";
} if (Number == 2){
    Number = "paper";
}

if (Number == userInput ){
    alert("TIE");
}   else if (Number == "scissors" && userInput == "paper"){
    alert("Scissors Win's");
}   else if (Number == "scissors" && userInput == "stone"){
    alert("Stone Win's");
}   else if (Number == "paper" && userInput == "scissors"){
    alert("Scissors Win's");
}   else if (Number == "paper" && userInput == "stone"){
    alert("Paper Win's");
}   else if (Number == "stone" && userInput == "scissors"){
    alert("Stone Win's");
}   else if (Number == "stone" && userInput == "paper"){
    alert("Paper Win's");
}
```

Comment: Check your console for errors

Comment: No errors :) @tymeJV

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle that reproduces the problem.

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you checked your variables all the way through the game?

Comment: Im guessing your final logic statements never  eval to `true` - and the code just finishes.

Comment: First of all, you should not use `Number` as a variable name, cause that is an existing global object already. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/49y3mkk0/ @GergoErdosi

Comment: I think so @the_pete Can't understand what to do.

Comment: Also, you can improve your game logic a bit. Right now you create 6 different possibilities for Rock vs Paper vs Scissors. You can make it more efficient by using nested if/else statements. See [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976883/rock-paper-scissors-in-javascript) for an example

Comment: Good to know @CBroe. Didn't know that. Will change it asap.

Comment: Putting my answer as a comment instead: Invoke `toLocaleLowerCase` (i.e. `toLocaleLowerCase()`) closing as a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main error was in this line:

```
var userInput = prompt("Choose between scissors, stone or paper. Good luck!").toLocaleLowerCase;
```

I fixed that to just call `.toLowerCase()` and I also updated your variable name to not be a global object and I also cleaned up your math and variable reassociation as you unnecessary code in both places. The code is below and you can check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vxkcw4u2/

```
var num = Math.random()
num = num * 10;
num = Math.round(num);
num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 + 1));

var userInput = prompt("Choose between scissors, stone or paper. Good luck!").toLowerCase();

if (num == 0) {num = "scissors";}
if (num == 1){num = "stone";}
if (num == 2){num = "paper";}

if (num == userInput ){alert("TIE");}
else if (num == "scissors" && userInput == "paper"){alert("Scissors Win's");}
else if (num == "scissors" && userInput == "stone"){alert("Stone Win's");}
else if (num == "paper" && userInput == "scissors"){alert("Scissors Win's");}
else if (num == "paper" && userInput == "stone"){alert("Paper Win's");}
else if (num == "stone" && userInput == "scissors"){alert("Stone Win's");}
else if (num == "stone" && userInput == "paper"){alert("Paper Win's");}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have error on line 8.

```
var userInput = prompt("Choose between scissors, stone or paper. Good luck!").toLocaleLowerCase;
```

change that line to

```
var userInput = prompt("Choose between scissors, stone or paper. Good luck!").toLowerCase();
```

Correct Code:

```
var Number = Math.random()
Number = Number * 10;
Number = Math.round(Number);
var Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 - 0 + 1)) + 0;

console.log (Number);

var userInput = prompt("Choose between scissors, stone or paper. Good luck!").toLowerCase();

console.log(userInput);

if (Number == 0) {
    Number = "scissors";
} if (Number == 1){
    Number = "stone";
} if (Number == 2){
    Number = "paper";
}



if (Number == userInput ){
        alert("TIE");
} else if (Number == "scissors" && userInput == "paper"){
    alert("Scissors Win\'s");
}   else if (Number == "scissors" && userInput == "stone"){
    alert("Stone Win\'s");
}   else if (Number == "paper" && userInput == "scissors"){
    alert("Scissors Win\'s");
}   else if (Number == "paper" && userInput == "stone"){
    alert("Paper Win\'s");
}   else if (Number == "stone" && userInput == "scissors"){
    alert("Stone Win\'s");
}   else if (Number == "stone" && userInput == "paper"){
    alert("Paper Win\'s");
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjzpubg0/)