# Javascript and HTML linking

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a Rock, Paper, Scissors javascript game. But, when I went to run it, I am having issues getting the HTML and the JS to communicate.

I have three buttons that are supposed to pass a string to the JS, which compares it with a random value that is assigned to the computer-player.

Any help getting this to function is greatly appreciated. Thanks

```js
   

     var choicePrompt = "Please, pick your poison.";
var victory = "Congrats, you Won!";
var defeat = "Sorry, you Lost";
var catsgame = "It's a draw!";

function run(userIn) {
 var loop = true;
 var winner;
 var scoreCount = 0;

 document.getElementById("prompt");

 while (loop)
 {
  compChoice = Math.random();
  compChoice = stringify(compChoice);
  userChoice = userIn;

  if (compChoice === "SOMETHING WENT WRONG")
  {
   document.getElementById("prompt").alert("JAVASCRIPT ERROR");
  }

  winner = victor(userIn, compChoice);

  switch (winner) {
   case "WIN":
    scoreCount += 1;
    document.getElementById("score") = "Score: " + scoreCount;
    document.getElementById("prompt").innerHTML = victory;
    break;

   case "LOSS":
    scoreCount -= 1;
    document.getElementById("score") = scoreCount;
    document.getElementById("prompt").innerHTML = defeat;
    break;

   case "DRAW":
    document.getElementById("prompt").innerHTML = catsgame;
    break;

   case "ERROR":

   default:
    document.getElementById("prompt").innerHTML = "Something went wrong";
  }
  loop = false;
 }
}

function stringify(float) {
 if (float <= 0.33)
 {
  return "ROCK";
 }
 else if (float > 0.33 && float <= 0.66)
 {
  return "PAPER";
 }
 else if (float > 0.66)
 {
  return "SCISSORS";
 }
 else
 {
  return "SOMETHING WENT WRONG";
 }
}

function victor(user, comp) {
 switch (user)
 {
  case "ROCK":
   switch (comp)
   {
    case "ROCK":
     return "DRAW";
     break;
    case "SCISSORS":
     return "WIN";
     break;
    case "PAPER":
     return "LOSS";
     break;
    default:
     return "ERROR";
   }
   break;
  case "PAPER":
   switch (comp)
   {
    case "ROCK":
     return "WIN";
     break;
    case "SCISSORS":
     return "LOSS";
     break;
    case "PAPER":
     return "DRAW";
     break;
    default:
     return "ERROR";
   }
   break;
  case "SCISSORS":
   switch (comp)
   {
    case "ROCK":
     return "LOSS";
     break;
    case "SCISSORS":
     return "DRAW";
     break;
    case "PAPER":
     return "WIN";
     break;
    default:
     return "ERROR";
   }
   break;
  default:
   return "ERROR";
 }
}
```

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/hmwk-3.css" />
   <script source src="play.js"></script>
</head>


<header>
  <h2>Rock, Paper, Scissors</h2>

  <nav>
    <a href="index.html">Homework Home</a> |
    <a href="welcome.html"> Play Rock, Paper, Scissors</a>
  </nav>
</header>


<body>
  <h3 id="prompt">Please, pick your poison.</h3><br>
 <h3 id="score">Score: 0</h3>

  <table>
    <td>
      <input type="image" src="../assets/hmwk-3/rock.png" onclick="run('ROCK')" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="image" src="../assets/hmwk-3/paper.png" onclick="run('PAPER')" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="image" src="../assets/hmwk-3/scissors.png" onclick="run('SCISSORS')" />
    </td>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I have updated the code, and the victory statement doesn't update. I can only get it to reach "It's a draw" if I pick Paper as the input. I also want this to run infinitely until the user leaves the page, do I need the loop to do this, or if they select a different picture, will it work fine without the loop. Thank you for the input

Comment: debug your code and ask a specific question..

Answer (score 2):

This works in FF. I was able to display all 3 conditions. You didnt set `loop` to false which created an infinite loop, and the `DRAW` case introduced a variable that hadn't been declared. And this can certainly be refactored, **which i will leave as an exercise for the OP**.

First credit on the infinite loop to @pL4Gu33.

```
var choicePrompt = "Please, pick your poison.";
var victory = "Congrats, you Won!";
var defeat = "Sorry, you Lost";
var catsgame = "Kiss yer sister";

function run(userIn) {
    var loop = true;
    var winner;
    var scoreCount = 0;

    while (loop)
    {
        compChoice = Math.random();
        compChoice = stringify(compChoice);
        userChoice = userIn;

        if (compChoice === "SOMETHING WENT WRONG")
        {
            document.getElementById("prompt").alert("JAVASCRIPT ERROR");
            loop = false;
        }

        winner = victor(userIn, compChoice);

        switch (winner) {
            case "WIN":
                document.getElementById("prompt").innerHTML = victory;
                loop = false;
                break;

            case "LOSS":
                document.getElementById("prompt").innerHTML = defeat;
                loop = false;
                break;

            case "DRAW":
                document.getElementById("prompt").innerHTML = catsgame;
                loop = false;
                break;

            case "ERROR":
                loop = false;
                break;
            default:
                loop = false;
                document.getElementById("prompt").innerHTML = "Something went wrong";
        }
    }
}

function stringify(float) {
    if (float <= 0.33)
    {
        return "ROCK";
    }
    else if (float > 0.33 && float <= 0.66)
    {
        return "PAPER";
    }
    else if (float > 0.66)
    {
        return "SCISSORS";
    }
    else
    {
        return "SOMETHING WENT WRONG";
    }
}

function victor(user, comp) {
    switch (user)
    {
        case "ROCK":
            switch (comp)
            {
                case "ROCK":
                    return "DRAW";
                    break;
                case "SCISSORS":
                    return "WIN";
                    break;
                case "PAPER":
                    return "LOSS";
                    break;
                default:
                    return "ERROR";
            }
            break;
        case "PAPER":
            switch (comp)
            {
                case "ROCK":
                    return "WIN";
                    break;
                case "SCISSORS":
                    return "LOSS";
                    break;
                case "PAPER":
                    return "DRAW";
                    break;
                default:
                    return "ERROR";
            }
            break;
        case "SCISSORS":
            switch (comp)
            {
                case "ROCK":
                    return "LOSS";
                    break;
                case "SCISSORS":
                    return "DRAW";
                    break;
                case "PAPER":
                    return "WIN";
                    break;
                default:
                    return "ERROR";
            }
            break;
        default:
            return "ERROR";
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with @Elliot-Rodriguez, this could be written a lot cleaner, take a look at some of the answers in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976883/rock-paper-scissors-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a variable declaration for `catsgame`, see the comment from  Elliot Rodriguez below and you while loop creates an infinite loop as `loop` is never set to `false`, see the comment from  pL4Gu33:

```js
var choicePrompt = "Please, pick your poison.";
var victory = "Congrats, you Won!";
var defeat = "Sorry, you Lost";
var catsgame = "It is a draw"; //added to the code, see Elliot Rodriguez' answer

function run(userIn) {
  var loop = true;
  var winner;
  var scoreCount = 0;

  while (loop) {
    compChoice = Math.random();
    compChoice = stringify(compChoice);
    userChoice = userIn;

    if (compChoice === "SOMETHING WENT WRONG") {
      document.getElementById("prompt").alert("JAVASCRIPT ERROR");
    }

    winner = victor(userIn, compChoice);

    switch (winner) {
      case "WIN":
        document.getElementById("prompt").innerHTML = victory;
        break;

      case "LOSS":
        document.getElementById("prompt").innerHTML = defeat;
        break;

      case "DRAW":
        document.getElementById("prompt").innerHTML = catsgame;
        break;

      case "ERROR":

      default:
        document.getElementById("prompt").innerHTML = "Something went wrong";
    }

    loop = false;//terminate loop, see comment by @pL4Gu33.
  }
}

function stringify(float) {
  if (float <= 0.33) {
    return "ROCK";
  } else if (float > 0.33 && float <= 0.66) {
    return "PAPER";
  } else if (float > 0.66) {
    return "SCISSORS";
  } else {
    return "SOMETHING WENT WRONG";
  }
}

function victor(user, comp) {
  switch (user) {
    case "ROCK":
      switch (comp) {
        case "ROCK":
          return "DRAW";
          break;
        case "SCISSORS":
          return "WIN";
          break;
        case "PAPER":
          return "LOSS";
          break;
        default:
          return "ERROR";
      }
      break;
    case "PAPER":
      switch (comp) {
        case "ROCK":
          return "WIN";
          break;
        case "SCISSORS":
          return "LOSS";
          break;
        case "PAPER":
          return "DRAW";
          break;
        default:
          return "ERROR";
      }
      break;
    case "SCISSORS":
      switch (comp) {
        case "ROCK":
          return "LOSS";
          break;
        case "SCISSORS":
          return "DRAW";
          break;
        case "PAPER":
          return "WIN";
          break;
        default:
          return "ERROR";
      }
      break;
    default:
      return "ERROR";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
  <script source src="play.js"></script>
</head>


<header>
  <h2>Rock, Paper, Scissors</h2>

  <nav>
    <a href="index.html">Homework Home</a> |
    <a href="welcome.html"> Play Rock, Paper, Scissors</a>
  </nav>
</header>


<body>
  <h3 id="prompt" />
  <table>
    <td>
      <input type="image" src="../assets/hmwk-3/rock.png" onclick="run('ROCK')" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="image" src="../assets/hmwk-3/paper.png" onclick="run('PAPER')" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="image" src="../assets/hmwk-3/scissors.png" onclick="run('SCISSORS')" />
    </td>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: He is missing a variable declaration for `catsgame` - I also ran it and added the variable but otherwise got it to run.

Comment: i am new in js but is that not a infinite loop in run method? Loop is never set false and the breaks are only for switch case

Comment: Yes @pL4Gu33 I just found it too. Nice catch.