# Javascript timer on text

Tags: javascript, html, css

scissors, paper game in javascript. The language is in Norwegian. I want to set a timer to a part of the text so that it will appear some seconds after the rest of the text.

Here's the code:

```
    <script>

        }
        var decide = prompt("Skriv inn enten (stein, saks eller papir)");
        var tekst="";
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1; // stein = 1 saks = 2 papir = 3

        if(decide === "stein" && random === 2) {
            tekst = "Du valgte stein, mens pc'en valgte saks. Du vant ";
        }
        else if(decide === "stein" && random === 3) {
            tekst = "Du valgte stein, mens pc'en valgte papir. Du tapte";
        }
        else if(decide === "stein" && random === 1) {
            tekst = "Du valgte stein, mens pc'en valgte stein. Uavgjort";
        }
        else if(decide === "saks" && random === 3) {
            tekst = "Du valgte saks, mens pc'en valgte papir. Du vant";
        }
        else if(decide === "saks" && random === 2) {
            tekst = "Du valgte saks, mens pc'en valgte saks. Uavgjort";
        }
        else if(decide === "saks" && random === 1) {
            tekst = "Du valgte saks, mens pc'en valgte stein. Du tapte";
        }
        else if(decide === "papir" && random === 3) {
            tekst = "Du valgte papir, mens pc'en valgte papir. Uavgjort";
        }
        else if(decide === "papir" && random === 2) {
            tekst = "Du valgte papir, mens pc'en valgte saks. Du tapte";
        }
        else if(decide === "papir" && random === 1) {
            tekst = "Du valgte papir, mens pc'en valgte stein. Du vant";
        }

        document.write(tekst);




    </script>
```

so that for example tekst = "Du valgte stein, mens pc'en valgte saks. Du vant ";
and then mens pc'en valgte saks. Du vant "; will appear 3 seconds later. Help pls

Comment: You can use `setTimeout` to add delay. Also your code is not valid and you can reduce your `if..else` ladder a lot

Comment: don't use `document.write`, there is simply no good reason to do so, get an element from the browser and then set the innerHTML. For the rest, check `setTimeout` for showing the text in a delayed way (3000 seems about what you want)

Answer (score 1):

Use `setTimeout` function.

```js
var decide = prompt("Skriv inn enten (stein, saks eller papir)");
var tekst = "";
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1; // stein = 1 saks = 2 papir = 3

if (['stein', 'saks', 'papir'].indexOf(decide) !== -1) {
  tekst = 'Du valgte ' + decide + 'mens pc\'en valgte ';

  switch (random) {
    case 1:
      tekst += 'stein';
      break;
    case 2:
      tekst += 'saks';
      break;

    case 3:
      tekst += 'papir';
      break;
  }

  var result = 'Uavgjort';

  switch (decide) {
    case 'stein':
      if (random == 2) {
        result = 'Du vant';
      } else if (random == 3) {
        result = 'Du tapte';
      }
      break;
    case 'saks':
      if (random == 1) {
        result = 'Du tapte';
      } else if (random == 3) {
        result = 'Du vant';
      }
      break;
    case 'papir':
      if (random == 2) {
        result = 'Du tapte';
      } else if (random == 1) {
        result = 'Du vant';
      }
      break;
  }

  var el = document.getElementById('output');
  el.innerHTML = tekst;

  setTimeout(function() {
    el.innerHTML += ' ' + result;
  }, 2000);
}
```

```html
<span id="output"></span>
```

---

Also if it's `scissors, paper, rock` game, than have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976883/rock-paper-scissors-in-javascript)

```js
var choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
var map = {};

choices.forEach(function(choice, i) {
    map[choice] = {};
    map[choice][choice] = "Was a tie"
    map[choice][choices[(i+1)%3]] = choices[(i+1)%3] + " wins"
    map[choice][choices[(i+2)%3]] = choice + " wins"
})

function compare(choice1, choice2) {
    return (map[choice1] || {})[choice2] || "Invalid choice";
}

alert(
  compare(
    prompt('Your choice (rock, paper, scissors)'),
    choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]
  )
);
```

Comment: @Icepickle Yes. With your example imagine that you have `rock, paper, scissors, lizard, Spok` game instead (or even bigger).

Comment: @Icepickle My switch is simply your code re-design.

Comment: It seems giving critic is a lot easier than taking it, and yes, your example would have a similar expanded switch case with multiple ifs in case you add spock and all the rest of your samples

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you could implement your rock/paper/sizzors game by making use of a dropdown, and showing the text in a delayed way.

The main point to show the text in a delayed way is this code:

```
function showResult( targetElement, text ) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById(targetElement).innerHTML = text;
    document.getElementById('runner').disabled = false;
  }, 3000);
}
```

it will delay the actual action by 3000 ms (3 seconds), and then show the text as part of the innerHTML of the target element (as you will see from the snippet, this will be a div)

```js
var values = [
  { value: 'rock', wins: ['sizzors'] }, 
  { value: 'paper', wins: ['rock'] }, 
  { value: 'sizzors', wins: ['paper'] }
];

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  function addOption(item, value) {
    var opt = new Option();
    opt.value = value;
    opt.text = value;
    item.options.add(opt);
  }
  
  var sel = document.getElementById('choice');
  addOption(sel, 'make your choice');
  for (var i = 0, len = values.length; i < len; i++) {
    addOption(sel, values[i].value );
  }
});

function resetResult() {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '';
  document.getElementById('runner').disabled = false;
}

function solve(sourceElement, targetElement) {
  document.getElementById('runner').disabled = true;
  var choice = document.getElementById(sourceElement);
  if (choice.selectedIndex <= 0) {
    alert('make your choice before clicking "Run"');
    return;
  }
  var choiceName = choice.options[choice.selectedIndex].value;
  var cpuValueIndex = parseInt(Math.random() * values.length);
  var cpuValue = values[cpuValueIndex];
  if ( cpuValue.value === choiceName ) {
    showResult( targetElement, 'Tie' );
  } else if ( cpuValue.wins.indexOf( choiceName ) >= 0 ) {
    showResult( targetElement, 'Cpu chose ' + cpuValue.value + ', you loose' );
  } else {
    showResult( targetElement, 'Cpu chose ' + cpuValue.value + ', you win' );
  }
}

function showResult( targetElement, text ) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById(targetElement).innerHTML = text;
    document.getElementById('runner').disabled = false;
  }, 3000);
}
```

```css
option, select {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<select id="choice" onchange="resetResult()">
</select>
<button type="button" id="runner" onclick="solve('choice', 'result')">Run</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```