# How to compare two different values after they have been changed already?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a rock paper scissors game, I’m using buttons that the user can choose from to either select rock paper or scissors, but I don’t know how to compare the results of the user’s answer and the computer’s answer to find out who won.

```
number = Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;

function results(){
    switch(number){
        case 6: case 5: var a = document.getElementById("computer").innerHTML="Rock";
        break;
        case 4: case 3: var b = document.getElementById("computer").innerHTML="Paper";
        break;
        case 2: case 1: var c = document.getElementById("computer").innerHTML="Scissors";
        break;
    }
}

function paper(){
    switch(true){
        case (number <= 6): var paper = document.getElementById("user").innerHTML="Paper";
        break;
    }
}

function rock(){
    switch(true){
        case (number <= 6): var rock = document.getElementById("user").innerHTML="Rock";
        break;
    }
}

function scissors(){
    switch(true){
        case (number <= 6): var rock = document.getElementById("user").innerHTML="Scissors";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `switch(true){
    case (number <= 6):` <--- a solution with `if` would be more readable and shorter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rock, Paper, Scissors in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976883/rock-paper-scissors-in-javascript)

Comment: Why are you using a switch as a conditional statement? Also, all your functions create local variables, then do nothing with them.

Answer (score 0):

You need only one function which will trigger when user click on any of options, then in same function you produce a choice for computer and then based on them figure out the winner. check the example below :

HTML :

```
<div id="c"></div>
<div id="u"></div>   
<div id="r"></div>
 // send parameter to function, 1 for Rock, 2 for Paper and 3 for Scissors
<button onclick="startg(1)">
  Rock
</button>
<button onclick="startg(2)">
  Paper
</button>
<button onclick="startg(3)">
   Scissors
</button>
```

Java script :

```
function startg(userChoice){

 document.getElementById("u").innerHTML="";
 document.getElementById("c").innerHTML="";
 document.getElementById("r").innerHTML="";

 var comNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1;

 switch (userChoice){
    case 1 : {
       document.getElementById("u").innerHTML="You Choosed : Rock";
       break;
      }
    case 2 : {
       document.getElementById("u").innerHTML="You Choosed : Paper";
       break;
      }
    case 3 : {
       document.getElementById("u").innerHTML="You Choosed : Scissors";
       break;
     }
 }

 switch (comNumber){
    case 1 : {
       document.getElementById("c").innerHTML="Compouter Choosed :Rock";
       break;
    }
   case 2 : {
       document.getElementById("c").innerHTML="Compouter Choosed :Paper";
       break;
    }
   case 3 : {
       document.getElementById("c").innerHTML="Compouter Choosed :Scissors";
       break;
    }
 }


    //Results :

    if (userChoice == 1 && comNumber==2)
       document.getElementById("r").innerHTML="Result : Computer Win!";
    else if (userChoice == 2 && comNumber==1)
       document.getElementById("r").innerHTML="Result : You Win!";
    else if (userChoice == 1 && comNumber==3)
       document.getElementById("r").innerHTML="Result : You Win!";
    else if (userChoice == 3 && comNumber==1)
       document.getElementById("r").innerHTML="Result : Computer Win!";
    else if (userChoice == 2 && comNumber==3)
       document.getElementById("r").innerHTML="Result : Computer Win!";
    else if (userChoice == 3 && comNumber==2)
       document.getElementById("r").innerHTML="Result : You Win!";
    else if (userChoice == comNumber)
       document.getElementById("r").innerHTML="Result : Draw";
 }
```

You can see a working example here : https://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/wpkj6rw6/4/